# How to get rid of a PPA?

Tags: debian, apt, repository, ppa

Whenever I do "sudo apt update" I am getting eventually:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

What I have tried:

---

- remove the file `developmentseed-mapbox-jessie.list` from`/etc/apt/sources.list.d`
- replace everything in the
  `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with:

  deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ oldstable main contrib non-free
  deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ oldstable main contrib non-free

  deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ oldstable-updates main contrib non-free
  deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ oldstable-updates main contrib non-free

  deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security oldstable/updates main
  deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security oldstable/updates main

  deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
  deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
- run `sudo apt update` and got the same stupid message and the file
  `developmentseed-mapbox-jessie.list` just reapeared in
  `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

---

- run `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:developmentseed/mapbox`
  running this command I am asked are you sure you want to remove this? Of course the answer is `yes`
- run `sudo apt update` and get the same initial error

  ---

So how on earth to get rid of this error?

### Additional Notes:

- The output for `grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` is:

  deb
     http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu jessie main
    # deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu jessie
     main

Comment: Welcome. Please add the output of `grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

Comment: I have updated the question with the answer at the "Additional Notes" section.

Comment: Ppas are meant for ubuntu and rarely work well with Debian, so trying to add that repo was more or less asking for trouble. I assume you also made sure no other file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` contained a reference to this repo? I find it hard to believe that a file appeared in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` as a result of running `apt update`, can you provide output proving that?

Comment: Did you need to install `tilemill`?

Comment: Yes, this is the root of the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The url isn't valid.

The possible codenames for the `ppa:developmentseed/mapbox` can be found [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/developmentseed/mapbox/ubuntu/dists/)

To solve the problem you should manually remove the file under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

```
# rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
# apt update
```

To install `tilemill` , install `nodejs` then follow the [installation guide](https://github.com/tilemill-project/tilemill).

```
$ sudo apt install build-essential git curl
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
$ sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
$ git clone https://github.com/tilemill-project/tilemill.git
$ cd tilemill
$ npm install
$ npm install sqlite3
$ ./index.js --server=true
```

Then type `localhost:20009` in your web browser.

Comment: Beware: This removes **all** additional repositories.

Comment: @Hermann Right , but in this case, there is only one file (see the output of `grep ^ ...)`

Comment: Suddenly it just worked with what you've answered. This is very awkward. Now the file did not appear again after removing it and running `apt update`. I've already tried this many times as written in the question.